# Web Application: the requested resource is not available after Maven clean

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets

I have a dynamic web project that has worked perfectly fine many times, but after going to Run As > Maven clean, I tried running my application again and when trying to go to the url http://localhost:8080/Servlet_Project/AccountServlet I get an error saying the requested resource is not available.  No exception is thrown - I can't seem to be able to access the servlet.  Here is my AccountServlet.java.  I also mapped the servlet in the web.xml but thought it was unnecessary because of the annotations.

```
@WebServlet("/AccountServlet")
public class AccountServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AccountServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/account.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

    HibernateClient hc = HibernateClient.getInstance();
    Accounts a = hc.getAccount(username, password);
            if(a==null){request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);

            }
            else{
            HttpSession sess = request.getSession(); 
            sess.setMaxInactiveInterval(600);
            sess.setAttribute("username", username);
            sess.setAttribute("firstName", a.getFirstname());
            sess.setAttribute("lastName", a.getLastname());
            sess.setAttribute("address", a.getAddress());
            sess.setAttribute("state", a.getState());
            sess.setAttribute("country", a.getCountry());
            sess.setAttribute("phone", a.getPhone());
            sess.setAttribute("SSN", a.getSsn());
            sess.setAttribute("email", a.getEmail());
            sess.setAttribute("city", a.getCity());
            String balances = (a.getBalance()).toString();
            double balance = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(balances)* 100d) 
            sess.setAttribute("balance", balance);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/account.jsp").forward(request, response);}}
}
```

Comment: To run the application you should do Run As --> Run on Server.  then select the server say "tomcat".

Comment: after Maven clean, you have to perform `mvn package` to build a new `war` file. This has to be deployed to Tomcat. I assume you're using Eclipse